# How can i only query required fields in graphql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, graphql-ruby

Is there any way that we can only query the required fields instead of querying the whole table every time?

For example, if I query like this:

```
query{
        locations(id:"", afterUpdatedAt:"2021-08-17", limit:"1", offset:"1"){
         
            businessName
            firstName
            lastName
            email
           
    
        }
    }
```

This is the request that is made:

```
Location Load (596.3ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE (updated_at >= '2021-08-17') LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2
```

My question is that the query should be made in a way that it should only load the required fields, and not the whole table.
If anyone knows the solution, please let me know.

Comment: I don't know if i understand you in the correct way, but it is not part of the query how it will be resolved and how the data is provided. That's part of your backend implementation. 

A fundamental part of graphql is schema first and both, your front- and backend, can develop against it.

Comment: I think he means the `locations.*` part of the select. There isn't a super elegant way other than using lookaheads and selecting only the fields required. Your mileage may vary but I don't think that is going to give you the performance boost you're looking for.